# adding filter exception on CSRF

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How do you add exception on csrf filtering..

On auth I did this on my controller and it is working fine

```
$this->beforeFilter( 'auth.user', array( 'except' => array( 'getDownload' ) ) );
```

but when I tried it on CSRF, exception it gives me this error

```
Illuminate\\Session\\TokenMismatchException
```

below is my code

```
$this->beforeFilter( 'csrf', array( 'on' => 'post', 'exception' => array( 'postDownloadBoot' ) ) );
```

I want to add csrf protection on most post methods but not on some methods

Hope anybody could help thanks

Comment: try using except instead of exception. Check this http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/41

Answer (score 1):

This Can be done in a simpler way.

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', [ 'on' => 'post',  'except' => 'postDownloadBoot' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work. Add this to your `__contruct` function

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', ['on' => 'post']);
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', ['except' => 'postDownloadBoot']
```

Comment: I recommend you to use array() instead of [] since this could cause problems in some servers.

Comment: Using `[]` is perfectly fine, any up to date server should support it. And if it doesn't work then you should look at updating the server rather than "downgrading" your code.

Comment: I like this solution.. but what if I have many methods in except? like postDownloadBoot, postBlahBlah, postBlahlah

Comment: I guess you can use an array like '["excepy"=>["postDownloadBoot", "postDownloadBoot", "postBlablabla"]]'